# Android studio 1.0.2 messages greyed out under View Menu

Tags: android-studio

If you look at the attached image, in Android Studio 1.0.2 I see the message tag greyed out (View -> Tool Windows -> Messages). I am trying to compile code and I dont see the error messages. What can cause this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So what exactly happens when you try to build your project?

Comment: What happens when you try the `Alt+0` shortcut?

Comment: @yole when I'm trying to build the project, I can only see errors if I go to a specific file with an error.

Comment: @Joel pressing it does exactly what Jon Snow knows - nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact problem. As it turned out, THe JDK update happened before that and all I had to do is to re-configure the JDK path from File->ProjectStructure->SDKLocation menu.